# How do I find out what type the elements of a zero length collection would be?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am writing a generic save object graph method.

If my object graph contains a collection, then it is possible that all the elements of the collection have been deleted.

In order to persist the deletes, I need to know what type of entities the collection is meant to hold.

```
navProps = GetNavigationProperties(originalEntity);
foreach (PropertyInfo navProp in navProps)
{

    Type propertyType = navProp.PropertyType;

    bool isCollection = propertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x == typeof(IEnumerable)) &&
                                            !(propertyType == typeof(string));

   object obj = navProp.GetValue(item);  

   if (isCollection) 
   {
       // I need to know what type the elements in the collection so I can retrieve the ones that might need deleting.
   }

}
```

Comment: Tell us what the original definition might look like, e.g. IList<T>, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two cases: either it's only `IEnumerable`, then you can only know that elements are of type `object`. This is what your code does currently.

The second possibility is that you have a strongly typed `IEnumerable<T>`, in which case you can do something like:

```
var enumerableTInterface = propertyType
    .GetInterfaces()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                                            == typeof(IEnumerable<>));

bool isStronglyTypedCollection = enumerableTInterface != null;

if (isStronglyTypedCollection)
{
    var elementType = enumerableTInterface.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    //...
```